# Firefox running very slow; Microphone does not work with Skype

Tags: firefox

Hi I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 and Firefox is running very slow. The Firefox version is 17.0.1.

Another problem I have is that my external microphone is not working on Skype.

So how Can I fix these problems?

Regards,
Kolyo

Comment: You have to separate problem into two topic, follow the rule here..

Answer (score 0):

Firefox running slow, you should try [RAMBack](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ramback/), A Firefox's add-on that work fine for me! And may you check other things such as graphic driver or consider 12.10.